# stacked on the sql query of bcrypting password php

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my php code**(Only the password part query)** with get the result working.

```
Query1 Working:          
               $sql  = "SELECT * FROM user ";
               $sql .= "WHERE username = '{$username}' ";
               $sql .= "AND password = '{$password}' ";
               $sql .= "AND level = '{$level}' ";
               $sql .= "LIMIT 1";
```

with the result of up it working fine i as i result i get the password correct.

but now i want **Hash** (**bcrypt**) the password. so i user the following coding

just want to change the **password to get HASH**:

```
Query2 Not Working:      $sql .= "AND password = $hash = crypt($password)";

                                               OR
                        $sql .= "AND password = '{$hash = crypt($password)}' ";
```

any idia how to make the **Query2 to use instead of Query1**

thanks

Comment: Don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: if we dont understand someones question does not mean to down mark him, ehehe recheck please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function will be interpreted as a string if it is enclosed under quotes.

The right way..

```
$sql .= "AND password = ".crypt($password);
```

You don't need the `$hash` in this context.